# Cursor loop iteration displaying every other values

Tags: android, loops, cursor

I'm trying to add all the values from all checkboxs that had been checked by the user. Furthermore, all checkboxes that aren't checked will be skiped. However, I am skipping one after every value. I need help.

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) 
{
    do
    { 
        if (cursor.getInt(10)>0 == false)
        {   
            cursor.moveToNext();
            n += cursor.getDouble(9);
        }

        else n += cursor.getDouble(9);

    } while(cursor.moveToNext());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Every* time you call `cursor.moveToNext()` it will go to the next row - you're calling it twice per loop (in your `while` clause, and in the `do`)

Just remove the call to `moveToNext()` in the `do` and you should be all set:

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) // <-- this will advance the cursor to the first row
{
    do
    { 
        if (cursor.getInt(10)>0 == false)
        {   
            //cursor.moveToNext(); <--you already called this!
            n += cursor.getDouble(9);
        }

        else n += cursor.getDouble(9);

    } while(cursor.moveToNext()); // <-- this advances the cursor

}
```

Comment: If I remove the `cursor.moveToNext()` I will get the sum of ALL the values. I just want values that are checked or `if (cursor.getInt(10)>0 == true)`

Answer (score 0):

You're doing moveToNext() too much

Try this to delete the one in the loop :

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()) 
{
  do
  { 
    if (cursor.getInt(10)>0 == false)
    {   
        n += cursor.getDouble(9);
    }

    else n += cursor.getDouble(9);

  } while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

Comment: Same answer as Sam_D, please check my reply